# How to ignore parts of the text and do search-and-replace in the remaining part?

Tags: regex, perl, replace, conditional-statements

While doing regex find-and-replace in text file, I wanna jump over & ignore certain segments of the text. That is, certain parts of the text should be excluded from the search, and only do search & replace in the remaining parts. The criteria is:

(1) anything between `START` and `END` should be excluded from the search & replace.
    `START` may or may not be at the start of a line;
    `END` may or may not be at the end of a line;
    one pair of `START` & `END` may span multiple lines;

(2) anything wihtin inline comment `//` should be ignored;
    `//` may or may not be at the start of line;

(3) the first word after `.` should be ignored;
    `.` may or may not be at the start of a line;
    the word may immediately follow `.` or with spaces, newlines, tabs splitting them.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

#iterate the DATA filehandle
while (<DATA>) {
    # This one replaces ALL occurrences of pattern.
    s/old/new/gs;

    # How do I skip the unwanted segments and do the replace?
    #print all
    print;
}

##inlined data filehandle for testing. 
__DATA__
xx START xx old xx END xx   --> ignore
xx old xx                   --> REPLACE !
START xx old                --> ignore
      xx old xx END         --> ignore
      xx old xx             --> REPLACE !
// xx old                   --> ignore
xx // xx old                --> ignore
xx . old old xx             --> ignore first one, replace second one
.
  old                       --> ignore
  (old) xx                  --> REPLACE !
xx old xx                   --> REPLACE !
```

Expected output is:

```
xx START xx old xx END xx   --> ignore
xx new xx                   --> REPLACE !
START xx old                --> ignore
      xx old xx END         --> ignore
      xx new xx             --> REPLACE !
// xx old                   --> ignore
xx // xx old                --> ignore
xx . old new xx             --> ignore first one, replace second one
.
  old                       --> ignore
  (new) xx                  --> REPLACE !
xx new xx                   --> REPLACE !
```

Can anyone help me with the regex here? I posted a similar question couple of hours ago, but that post was full of ambiguities and precludes a clear answer. Hopefully this post may be a "good" & "clear" question.

Comment: I'll remove my answer. [Did you try it?](https://regex101.com/r/yI0jH2/3)

Comment: I'm trying; have not found a solution yet >_<

Comment: [`How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/5527985)

Comment: @bobblebubble They work perfect! Many thanks to your post (which you deleted); based on your code I solved my problem!

Comment: @bobblebubble  Your original post is like: `s/(?:(?s:START.*?END)|\/\/.*|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/gs;`; I changed it to `s/(?:(?:START.*?END)|\/\/.*?\n|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/gs;` (so that comments will terminate at end of line, which is \n) and it totally solved the problem! Thank you~

Comment: Also try `s/(?:(?s:START.*?END)|\/\/.*|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/g;` It probably failed because you use `/gs` the `s` flag at the end which makes the dot in all pattern match newline. I only used the inline modifier `(?s:` for the part where it's needed.  However, great you got it going :) restored answer as it seemed to be of help to solve problem.

Comment: @bobblebubble Yep, you're right. It's just either putting the `/s` flag inside or outside; glad I learned from you and @Jan the `(?s:...` syntax. Is it OK that I close this question with my own reply stating the final solution?

Comment: This is a really good example of why a 'single regex' solution to problems is a bad idea.

Comment: @Sobrique Your replies have always been inspiring :-) Any further explanations on this? If "single regix" does work, why is it bad?

Comment: Imagine you come back to this code in 6 months time, and need to alter your regex. How much chance do you have of doing understanding it?

Comment: @Sobrique Got that ;-) I figure you're talking about "What the hell is this!?" coding style. My solution is to use comments and documentations to document these "tricky" parts; hopefully they'll give me chance to understand it 6 months later :)

Comment: Yes. But the thing is - you have a code snippet that is going to be very hard to understand, and thus _requires_ documentation. However, if you have written out the algorithm longhand in `perl` rather than using `regex` as a programming language, then you'd end up with something that didn't actually require that. That's why I really object to the "magic regex" solutions, because they're MUCH harder to maintain, for no real benefit aside from 'looking clever'.

Comment: @Sobrique Got that; learning it. Thank you~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) to skip something.

```
(?:(?s:START.*?END)|\/\/.*|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old
```

It works like this: `(?:part 1 to skip|part 2 to skip|...)(*SKIP)(*F)` `|` `part to match`

- `(?:` opens a [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for alternation `(?s:` with `s` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make dot match newline
- `\w` matches a [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yI0jH2/3)

Comment: Thanks; I'm checking it out.

Comment: @katyusza I thought it's obvious, that you need to use `old` or whatever in the part to match, [see update](https://regex101.com/r/yI0jH2/3).

Comment: Yes, either one of the following can do what I want: (1) `s/(?:(?:START.*?END)|\/\/.*?\n|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/gs;` (2) `s/(?:(?s:START.*?END)|\/\/.*|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/g;` (3) `s/(?:START.*?END|\/\/.*?\n|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/gs;`

Comment: @katyusza [The dot default matches any character besides newline](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). So it would NOT skip over newlines by default. That the dot matches newlines was only needed for the `START.*?END` part which could span across multiple lines. That's why I used the inline [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) only for this part.

Comment: In my intention, the newline may also appear between `.` and `pattern`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more precise on your structue (i.e. when old should be ignored), but for your example the following regex will work ([demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kZ7lW3/1)):

```
~                                       # delimiter
    (?s)(?:START).*?(?:END)(?-s)|       # look for START-END in single-line mode OR
    //.+|                               # everything after two forward slashes
    \.\sold|                             # the word old after a dot and space OR
    ^\s+old                             # old after spaces at the beginning of the line
    (*SKIP)(*FAIL)|                     # all these matches shall fail
    \b(old)\b                           # this one is to be kept
~xg                                     # verbose and multiline modifier
```

To read more about the concept, check this fantastic site - [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Comment: The demo exactly matches what I intended, but when I put it into `s///gs`, it issues an error: `syntax error at ... line .., near "+|"`, `Substitution pattern not terminated at ... line 10.`

Comment: You need to use other delimiters: `~` instead of the forward slashes - otherwise, you need to escape the slashes like `\/\/`.

Comment: I escaped it using `\/\/`, now in the output file some stuffs are missing, which is not desired. I want full text to be printed.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want full text to be printed" ?

Comment: I mean, I use `s/(?s)(?:START).*?(?:END)(?-s)|\/\/.+|\. old|^\s+old(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(old)\b/new/gs;` in my code, and in the output result, first line becomes stuff like `xx new xx    --> ignore`, the leading "xx START" and trailing "END xx" are gone.

Comment: This is also the right answer :) Probably the key is to understand how `(*SKIP)(*F)` works.

Comment: @bobblebubble Yep; I'm just googling (*SKIP)(*F) stuff >,<

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the valuable contributions from @bobblebubble and @Jan, and based on the Perl code in their replies, I eventually learned to use (*SKIP)(*F) to skip, jumper over or ignore unwanted segments. The final code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

#iterate the DATA filehandle
while (<DATA>) {
    # This one replaces ALL occurrences of pattern.
#    s/old/new/gs;

    # How to skip the unwanted segments and do the replace:
    # Both are good.
    #s/(?:(?:START.*?END)|\/\/.*?\n|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/gs;
    s/(?:(?s:START.*?END)|\/\/.*|\.\s*\w+\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|old/new/g;
    #print all
    print;
}

##inlined data filehandle for testing. 
__DATA__
xx START xx old xx END xx   --> ignore
xx old xx                   --> REPLACE !
START xx old                --> ignore
      xx old xx END         --> ignore
      xx old xx             --> REPLACE !
// xx old                   --> ignore
xx // xx old                --> ignore
xx . old old xx             --> ignore first one, replace second one
.
  old                       --> ignore
  (old) xx                  --> REPLACE !
xx old xx                   --> REPLACE !
```

And, again, many thanks to bobble bubble and Jan.